# How to call a function JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery-ui, razor, datetimepicker, webmatrix

I'm a beginner in JQuery (I know nothing about this framework).

I recently found a code to display a calendar or hours using JQuery and very cool.

How can I use this code?

Follow the link to the code I'm trying to implement in my system (with Razor WebMatrix)

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: As a start, I suggest you read some tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: Are you beginner with jQuery or more with JavaScript at all?

Comment: I understand some JavaScript but almost nothing JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of including the necessary script and style references, then wiring the components. In this particular case:

1. Include the jQuery engine core script within the `<head>` of your page. Use the most recent version available (currently, 1.5). The script in your sample page uses jQuery 1.4.4:

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>`
2. Include the jQuery UI core script as well (same here about the version):

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js"></script>`
3. Include the plugin script(s):

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>`
4. Don't forget to reference the plugin UI elements styles:

   `<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css">`
5. Wire the plugin with the text box element which will act as the calendar trigger. That sample uses a `<input type=text>` whose ID is `example1`:

   `$('#example1').datetimepicker();`

These are general steps for this particular case! jQuery offers much more functionality, and exploiting it may require other setups. But the example you chose is a good starting point: it's useful and easy to understand. Boa sorte...

Comment: I use the concept of the LayoutPage in WebMatrix, the tag header is on another page.

This has influence on the code?

How do I post my code in Stackoverflow for you to take a look?

Comment: It doesn't matter really, just be careful to include the scripts and styles accordingly. Pay attention to relative URLs if your pages spread across directories in the site. And remember to wire things up using the $(document).ready() event handler. Perhaps you can post some code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)...

Comment: I put the full code, I made a change to see how JQuery works as suggested by DSW but failed.
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/Fd4Zu/

Comment: @Riederman, see an updated version at jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Fd4Zu/1/). I removed all Razor code because it is server-side code, and thus jsFiddle will ignore it.

Comment: worked!
But several were dúvias.
1. How can I change the theme (put the blue theme)
2. As the link below, I modified two scripts tags but the two listed the link is not understood why I had to add it to my project.
[Scripts](http://jsfiddle.net/Riderman/nqGpd/1/)

Comment: Try the jQueryUI [Packager](http://jqueryui.com/download) to pack the necessary components and select themes. The scripts you mentioned are the core scripts for jQuery and jQueryUI, both of which are mandatory for the functioning of the calendar!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to reference the JQuery core libraries in your html, which you can either reference via a CDN, such as Google's or by downloading the .js files.  If you'd just like to use Google's CDN here is the link to the jQuery js file:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js
```

Next download the .js and any other files required by that jQuery plugin and reference them in your html.

Follow the examples on the site then to add the calendar to your html.

Also, read up on JQuery here ->  http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page

Good luck.